# PHP new line array, look ahead

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I have the following code routine, which is preg_match ing xml elements and printing the attributes of those elements.

However, in some of the tags, the content does not appear on one line (the SCRIPT tag), and therefore doesnt get matched.

I am wondering how to look ahead and gather all the lines until the closing tag "/>" ?

Is it possible to use the @ character somewhere in the preg_match, to allow new lines?

I'm not even sure about how to go about resolving this. I've done a PHP sandbox so the code can be tested online:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f96daef33fb49179eee30250ded81af6a8e5c567

If I remove all the data in the script tag, all apart from the first line, then it correctly outputs the array.

```
$file = '    <TOPTAG class="Menu" text="FCLPHP" >
        <TAG1 name="contain=" />
        <SCRIPT name="check()" script="if(B3||B4||B5 == 1){
        do(ABC,0);
        do(BCD,1);" />
    </WINDOW>
';

//split the string into an array based on new line
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

//count the number of lines
$linesLength = count($lines);

for($index = 0; $index < $linesLength; $index++){

    //reads all element atrributes from the TOPTAG element
    $reads = element_attributes('TOPTAG',$lines[$index]);   

    //reads all element atrributes from the SCRIPT element
    $scripts = element_attributes('SCRIPT',$lines[$index]);

    //prints the script tag attributes
    print_r($scripts); 
}


function element_attributes($element_name, $xml) {
    if ($xml == false) {
        return false;
    }
    // Grab the string of attributes inside an element tag.
    $found = preg_match('#<'.$element_name.
            '\s+([^>]+(?:"|\'))\s?/?>#',
            $xml, $matches);
    if ($found == 1) {
        $attribute_array = array();
        $attribute_string = $matches[1];
        // Match attribute-name attribute-value pairs.
        $found = preg_match_all(
                '#([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*(\'[^<\']*\'|"[^<"]*")#',
                $attribute_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($found != 0) {
            // Create an associative array that matches attribute
            // names to attribute values.
            foreach ($matches as $attribute) {
                $attribute_array[$attribute[1]] =
                        substr($attribute[2], 1, -1);
            }
            return $attribute_array;
        }
    }
    // Attributes either weren't found, or couldn't be extracted
    // by the regular expression.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *"which is preg_match ing xml elements"* -- do you have any serious reason to not use the [`SimpleXML` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) or [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)? Their only purpose in life is to work with XML in an easy and pleasant way.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I cannot work with either of these because the xml is not well formed.

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes, I was thinking to use /m for multiline, but I'm not sure how, tried a few ways. Although I think the problem is deeper than that, because I am only feeding the function 1 line at a time, I believe, so I'm not sure how to tackle this

Comment: Your regexp will match across multiple lines. The problem is that you're using `explode('\n', $file)` and then processing it one line at a time. If you just work with `$file` as one big string it should do what you want.

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes agreed. The problem is I have written a lot of code this way, and will need to adapt all of the code to work with strings rather than lines. I was kinda hoping there is a way to do it by reading lines

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that. If you call the function with just one line, how can it possibly match something that extends into the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp operates across multiple lines. The problem is that you're only using it on one line at a time, so it never sees the continuation. Don't split the file into lines, just work with it as a single string.

```
$reads = element_attributes('TOPTAG',$file);
$scripts = element_attributes('SCRIPT',$file);
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this doesn't work when I try to use file_get_contents, I'm not sure why, it works fine when I just use the string.

Comment: Then either there's something wrong with the regexp or the file contents don't contain what you expect. How a variable is assigned makes no difference to the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this. You were right, it needed a / in the regex in front of the last /? - e.g.  '#<'.$element_name.'\s+([^>]+(?:"|\'))\s?\/?>#',

Comment: `/` has no special meaning in the regexp, I don't understand why you need to escape it.

Comment: Yes its strange, I got told to add this using https://regex101.com/r/frF0eC/5 and it worked

Comment: That's because regex101 uses `/` as the delimiter around the regexp. But PHP allows you to use any character as the delimiter, and you're using `#` instead of `/`.